# How to login in admin panel in croogo cakephp framwork

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.1

Hi i am lost my login detail how to change password from phpmyadmin. I am change users table give password in password field in hash but it does not open dashboard it show invalid user or password.

Comment: i really don t understand your problem

Comment: Please write proper english as we are at total lost. Use google translate if required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must check if this is not an encoding problem, Croogo encrypt the passwords before saving it and if you change your password in database it will not match.

You can try to using Croogo shell to reset password by :

```
$ ./Console/cake users.users reset admin password
```

More details and documentation [here](http://docs.croogo.org/1.5/en/developers/shells.html).

Hope that will help you..